# Updating the millisecond parameter of setInterval function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a slider that is displaying quotes. Some quotes are longer than others and I'd like to provide the user adequate time to read them. The timer variable is getting updated in the changeQuote function, but its not updating the paramater of the setInterval function. How can I update the milliseconds parameter of the setInterval? Thanks

```
var quotes=[{quote:'lorem ipsum', name:'test'},{quote:'lorem ipsum ipsum 2', name:'test2'}];

var x=0;
var l = quotes.length;
var ql=0;
var timer=0;

function quoteInit(){
    if(x==l) x=0;
    ql = quotes[x]['quote'].length;
    $('.quote').find('h4').html(quotes[x]['quote']);
    $('.quote').find('p').html(quotes[x]['name']);
    timer=(ql*110);
    x++;
    changeQuote(timer); 
}

function changeQuote(timer){
    console.log(timer);
    setInterval(quoteInit,timer);
}

quoteInit();
```

Comment: `setInterval` means to run the provided function *every* X milliseconds.  What you are doing is creating *multiple* intervals that are *all* running at the same time.  You need to either a) use `setTimeout` instead or b) clear the interval - using `clearInterval()` - before re-setting it.

Comment: You would have to create a function to stop and restart the timer with the new time interval. Edit: Ah, Rocket Hazmat beat me to the punch.

Comment: @s1h4d0w: Don't worry, I still up-voted your comment :)

Comment: Thanks guys, unfortunately I've tried both with no avail. Can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to my comment, use something like this to stop and start your timer again:

```
function start() {
    theTimer = setInterval(quoteInit,timer);
};

function stop() {
    clearInterval(theTimer);
};
```

Simply call `stop()` and `start()` when you want to reset the timer with a different interval (after changing `timer` ofcourse). This will stop the timer (with your old `timer` value) and start it again with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody said, just changing `setInterval` to `setTimeout` works fine:

```js
var quotes=[{quote:'short', name:'test'}, {quote:'medium ipsum', name:'test2'},{quote:'long lorem ipsum ipsum', name:'test3'}];

var x=0;
var l = quotes.length;
var ql=0;
var timer=0;

function quoteInit(){
    if(x==l) x=0;
    ql = quotes[x]['quote'].length;
    $('.quote').find('h4').html(quotes[x]['quote']);
    $('.quote').find('p').html(quotes[x]['name']);
    timer=(ql*110);
    x++;
    changeQuote(timer); 
}

function changeQuote(timer){
    console.clear();
    console.log(timer);
    setTimeout(quoteInit,timer);
}

quoteInit();
```

```css
body{ font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center; }
h4{ font-size: 2em; font-weight: 700; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="quote">
  <h4></h4>
  <p></p>
</div>
```